# register_sidebar / dynamic_sidebar with sidebar id

Tags: register-sidebar

I am trying to get rid of the following error in debug:

```
Notice: register_sidebar was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. 
No <code>id</code> was set in the arguments array for the "Header" sidebar.
```

So when I register that sidebar I added the id parameter like so:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'header-sidebar',
    'name' => 'Header',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Now no matter if I use the name field or the id field `dynamic_sidebar` always returns false.

I've tried:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'Header' );
```

and

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'header-sidebar' );
```

My understand is both of the above should work.  Note if I comment out the id parameter in the register_sidebar call and use `dynamic_sidebar( 'Header' );` everything works fine.  What am I missing?

This is WP 4.2.2.

So per these directions: [List all sidebar names?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/list-all-sidebar-names) I was able to list all the sidebar names and when I set the id parameter with `register_sidebar` the id in the list of names changes.  The specific sidebar I'm playing with now is 'sidebar-5' before setting an id and 'sidebar-jsp' after.  Once the id field is set I can not use `dynamic_sidebar` with the name 'Sidebar', the original id 'sidebar-5' or the new id 'sidebar-jsp'.

Per s_ha_dum's suggestion I wrapped a single sidebar inside a function so that I could make it happen after 'widgets_init'.  This did not work.

```
function register_header_sidebar_jsp() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar-jsp',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_header_sidebar_jsp' );
```

I'm calling it right now with:

```
<?php var_dump(dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-jsp')); ?>
```

I'm not sure what's going on but I don't have all day to mess with this.  Thanks for your suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works when I test it. I can only assume that the registration code is being hooked into the system too early or too late. [`register_sidebar()` should be hooked on `widgets_init` per the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar). Therefore:

```
function register_header_sidebar_wpse_190618() {
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'id' => 'header-sidebar',
      'name' => 'Header',
      'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
      'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
      'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_header_sidebar_wpse_190618' );
```

Comment: I'm glad it works for someone.

Comment: Something is broken about your site. You add a widget to the sidebar right? Or does it not show up on the back end at all?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine if I don't specify an 'id' parameter.  I only added the 'id' parameter to get rid of debug error messages but this is clearly worse.  It shows up in the backend under Appearance > Widgets and again is clearly 'registered'.  But again `dynamic_sidebar` always returns false when I add an id parameter to `register_sidebar`.

Comment: Is there already a sidebar with that I'd?

Comment: I'd qualify this as a bug. @Tosho [has a good answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59973/what-is-allowed-as-an-id-argument-in-register-sidebar-args/59985#59985) that will most likely provide more insight here...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'new-header-sidebar' ); ?>

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Header', 'theme-slug' ),
    'id' => 'new-header-sidebar',
) );
```

You may have a I.D conflict so try changing the I.D

Comment: No idea why but this did not work for me.  I'm not sure if the suggestion was more about using __() or removing the other parameters but I copy and pasted this with no luck.

Comment: Here's the full code which is tested and works http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190611/9884

Comment: Please don't just dump some code, and add some explanation. Code-only answers are not good, I'm afraid.

Comment: I did add the explanation as a comment. I think you must have missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Try starting the `id` field value with 'sidebar'.

If that doesn't work, the order shouldn't matter, but try following the codex example:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'description' => __( 'show on all posts and pages', 'theme-slug' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

Also try not using the word 'header' in the `id` field.